# Python 3.4.2 - Socket module is not callable

Tags: python, sockets, typeerror

```
from socket import *
import _thread
from My_TCP_callable import *

IP_list = []
port_list = []

def IP_find(IP_list):
    IPtarget = input("Enter host to scan: ")

    IP_list = []
    print ('Starting scan on host ', IPtarget)

    for ip in range(1, 256):
        s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

        addr = IPtarget + str(ip)
        result = s.connect_ex((addr, 135))
        print (ip)

        if(result == 0):
            print ('IP %d: OPEN' % (addr,))
            IP_list.append(str(addr))
        s.close()
    print("Open ports: %s" % (port_list))
    sending_socket(port_list)
    return

def port_find(port_list):
    if __name__ == '__main__':

        target = input('Enter host to scan: ')

        possible_list = []
        port_list = []

        typ = int(input(" 1.Use standard ports \n 2.Set a range of points \n     3+.Set a number of specific points "))

        if typ == 1:
            possible_list = [20, 1025]
        else:
            for number in range(typ):
                v = int(input("Set a port point: "))
                possible_list.append(v)

        if typ >= 3:
            x = (possible_list)
        else:
            x = range(min(possible_list), max(possible_list))

        targetIP = gethostbyname(target)
        print ('Starting scan on host ', targetIP)

        #scan reserved ports
        for i in x:
            s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

            result = s.connect_ex((targetIP, i))

            if(result == 0):
                print ('Port %d: OPEN' % (i,))
                port_list.append(str(i))
            s.close()
        print("Open ports: %s" % (port_list))
    return port_list

def sending_socket(port_list):
    send_socket = input("Would you like to send a socket with this? ")
    if send_socket == "yes":

        port = int(input("Which port would you like to search? "))
        message = input("What would you like to send? ")

        My_TCP_callable.connect(targetIP, port, message)
    elif send_socket == "automate":
        message = "Alive"
        for ports in port_list:
            _thread.start_new_thread(connect ,(targetIP, ports, message))
    return

IP_find(IP_list)
```

Every time I call this code an error comes up:

File "C:\Users\as009542\Desktop\python\Networking\scanner.py", line 81, in

```
<module>
    IP_find(IP_list)
  File "C:\Users\as009542\Desktop\python\Networking\scanner.py", line 15, in IP_find
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I've checked around and used this in other programs but I cant figure out why the socket can't create.
This code is not pretty or complete however I can't continue making it until I fix this problem, the last function 'sending_socket' is being called from a different file called 'My_TCP_callable' although this does not affect the problem I am having.

Comment: do you have socket.py in that folder too?

Comment: Show us all of your code. This is not all of it. What does `print socket` print?

Comment: Sorry, I've put it all up now, but I can't find where i'm using 'print socket'

Comment: You can put the `print socket` before the last line (the IP_find line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using `import socket` in your module `My_TCP_callable`

Because you use

```
from socket import *
from My_TCP_callable import *
```

Everything from each module is imported, and the socket names are clashing (preference is given to the one from `My_TCP_callable`.

I reproduced this behaviour with two files, test2.py which contained one line, `import socket`, and test.py which contained

```
from socket import *
from test2 import *
socket()
```

A good coding style is to use `from ... import *` very rarely, and only on modules specifically designed for it.

Comment: Thank you, didn't realize using it in a different file would affect this